# Windows 7 BSOD - ntoskrnl.exe MEMORY_MANAGEMENT 0x0000001a

Tags: windows-7, windows, bsod

Turned my computer on, went to brush my teeth, came back and it was recovering from a BSOD. Same errors from a couple past BSOD's within the last month. Not sure what could be causing it, help would be much appreciated!

Windows 7 Home Premium, NVIDIA GTX 1070, Intel i5-2500, ASUS P8-Z68-V LX

Dump:

```
081616-33353-01.dmp 8/16/2016 11:43:37 PM   MEMORY_MANAGEMENT   0x0000001a  00000000`00000031   fffffa80`0a39dbd0   fffff880`00b99000   fffff8a0`1f4c86cc   ntoskrnl.exe    ntoskrnl.exe+6f400  NT Kernel & System  Microsoft® Windows® Operating System    Microsoft Corporation   6.1.7601.23455 (win7sp1_ldr.160516-0600)    x64 ntoskrnl.exe+6f400                  C:\Windows\Minidump\081616-33353-01.dmp 4   15  7601    408,200 8/16/2016 11:45:18 PM
```

Please let me know if more information is needed!

Dump Debug:
http://pastebin.com/6mBniwkS

Module list: http://pastebin.com/xFmVmMdG

Comment: Use `Windbg` and analyze `C:\Windows\Minidump\081616-33353-01.dmp`

Comment: Realized its wrong, it's early in the AM, running a bugcheck now. Paste: http://pastebin.com/6mBniwkS

Comment: I think your system crashed during [this](https://blogs.msdn.microsoft.com/dotnet/2013/08/06/wondering-why-mscorsvw-exe-has-high-cpu-usage-you-can-speed-it-up/) and you must do [this](https://support.microsoft.com/en-in/kb/2571181)

Comment: I'll look into it, here's a module paste: http://pastebin.com/xFmVmMdG

Looking into it I don't see a .NET service running, and I've never had that issue the article describes.

Comment: check your RAM with memtest86+